# Using C#, how can I display an XML line by line?

Tags: c#, xml, listbox, linq-to-xml

Hy,

I have for example this xml:

```
<books>
  <book1 name="Cosmic">
    <attribute value="good"/>
  </book1>
</books>
```

How can I display it in a listBox control line by line, that the final result it will be a listbox with 5 rows in this case?

In this moment I am prasing the XML using LINQ to XML like this:

```
 foreach (XElement element in document.DescendantNodes())
   {
     MyListBox.Items.Add(element.ToString());
   }
```

But the final result puts every xml node in one list-box item (including child-nodes).

Does anyone has any idea how can I put the xml line by line in list-box items?

Thanks.

Jeff

Comment: Why do you want to put it in a listbox?

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann - why does it matter?

Comment: @Oded, it matters because it sounds like a strange requirement, and maybe the OP is trying to achieve something that could be done easier using another control/approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would use a recursive function like the following:

```
public void FillListBox(ListBox listBox, XElement xml)
{
    listBox.Items.Add("<" + xml.Name + ">");
    foreach (XNode node in xml.Nodes())
    {
        if (node is XElement)
            // sub-tag
            FillListBox(listBox, (XElement) node);
        else
            // piece of text
            listBox.Items.Add(node.ToString());
    }
    listBox.Items.Add("</" + xml.Name + ">");
}
```

Of course, this one will print only the tag names (e.g. `<book1>` in your example) and not the attributes (`name="Cosmic"` etc.). I’m sure you can put those in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your raw XML in a list box, use a text stream to read in your data.

```
using(StreamReader re = File.OpenText("Somefile.XML"))
{
  string input = null;
  while ((input = re.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    MyListBox.Items.Add(input);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, maybe it would be much easier to implement (and to read/maintain) with a simple TextReader.ReadLine()?
I don't know what you are trying to achieve, just a suggestion.